# .htaccess RewriteEngine causing Unexpected 403 Forbidden http response code in xampp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp, http-status-code-403

I am using xampp to test out some php code.

In the main project directory, I have the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

#Index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/$  
RewriteRule request_handler.php [L]

#php files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*(\.php)$
RewriteRule . request_handler.php [L]

#Blocked files. PHP blocked files should be specified in request_handler.php
<Files "setup.json">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
<Files "testimonials.json">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

#CACHE CONTROLL FOR STATIC RESOURSES
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Anyhow, I am getting an unexpected 403 forbidden in all my requests. If I remove the first line of the .htaccess file though, I stop getting that unsuspected behavior.

Does anyone know what might be causing this error?

**UPDATE**
I have created a new .htaccess file, that only contains one line: `RewriteEngine On` and I still get the error. (If I remove that line, I stop getting the error). The sole presence of that line causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, all I had to do was add the line `Options FollowSymLinks` before the `RewriteEngine On` directive.

Here's what Apache has to say:

> To enable the rewrite engine in this context, you need to set "RewriteEngine On" and "Options FollowSymLinks" must be enabled. [...] This restriction is required for security reasons.

[Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#:%7E:text=To%20enable%20the,for%20security%20reasons.)